# How to keep hover rule on top of Bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working on the below snippet. How can I keep hover rule affected on `.btn-default` while still hovering on it's associated `.dropdown-menu`?

```js
$(function(){
    $('.btn-dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
body{
padding:30px;
}
.btn-default:hover{
    color:red !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group btn-dropdown" role="group">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      List One
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
<div class="btn-group btn-dropdown" role="group">
    <a role="button" class="btn  btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      List Two
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See If this is what you exactly looking for. I have added `.open` parent in your CSS and removed `.hover`

Whenever you are appending `.open` class it will add the CSS

```js
$(function(){
    $('.btn-dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
body{
padding:30px;
}
.open .btn-default{
    color:red !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group btn-dropdown" role="group">
    <a role="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      List One
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
<div class="btn-group btn-dropdown" role="group">
    <a role="button" class="btn  btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      List Two
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```